# Test file copy in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, tdd

I'm trying to implement TDD and code coverage in my new projects but for a current one I am creating some test but I have multiple doubts about it. Here I share the class I created to copy one file from my file system :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.google.common.io.Files;

@Component
public class CopyXMLFileToResources {


    @Value("${xml.routing.folder}")
    private String XML_FOLDER;

    @Value("${resources.folder}")
    private String RESOURCES_FOLDER;

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CopyXMLFileToResources.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.files.copy}", zone = "${zone.files.copy}")
    public void copyXMLFile() throws IOException {

    LOG.info("Copying the lastest varsion of  Delta file ...");

    File directory = validateDirectory(XML_FOLDER);

    if (directory.canRead()) {

        try {

        File origin = Utils.prepareDeltaFile(directory);
        if (origin != null) {
            File copied = new File(RESOURCES_FOLDER + origin.getName());
            if (copied.getTotalSpace() > 0) {
            LOG.info("Last version already copied.");
            }
            else {
                try {
                    Files.copy(origin, copied);
                    LOG.info(
                        "Copying the  DELTA file successful");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            LOG.warn("No matching files fouded in {}",
                directory.getCanonicalPath());
        }

        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage()); 
        }

    }
    else {
        LOG.warn("Cannot read folder {}. ", XML_FOLDER);
    }

    }

    private File validateDirectory (String folder) {
    return new File(folder);
    }

    public String printString(String s ) {
    return s;
    }

}
```

I know there are so many things to improve, but my first question is, what  functionalities must be tested and how to start? Because I created a Test class but I do not know what to test, I tryed to start testing the access to the folder but that makes me question about if do I need to return something like a integer code depending of the case for example 0 for Folder access denied, 1 when all is OK for example. 
This class only have one public method and is a void one. I also have the question about the properties I am using:

`application.properties`:

```
xml.routing.folder=../../xml
resources.folder=src/main/resources/
cron.files.copy=0 1 1 * * *
zone.files.copy=Europe/Paris
```

Is this correct? If I migrate the project to another server, the access to the folder that contains the xml may be denied. I haven't created Test before so I appreciate resources to start specially in TDD.

Comment: i'd personally have your copyXMLFile return different error codes. Typically, in WIndows for example, an error code of 0 is success. Think of ways your copy could fail, like restricted access, the file doesn't exist and so on and have error codes for each scenario.

Comment: If you wanted to do TDD, you would first write a test, based on requirements for the feature, checked that it failed correctly, and then write the code to implement the feature and make the test pass. Then you would perhaps refactor the implementation code to improve it, and after that the TDD cycle would repeat for the next feature. The most important thing to understand about TDD - and many fail to - is that you test *features*, not implementation code.

Comment: *"what functionalities must be tested and how to start?"* You needs to test all functionalities that your program needs to have. And you start with the one that is easiest to test and/or implement.

Answer (score 0):

The name method is copyXMLFile so i test whether actually a new file .xml exist in a given folder. 
So you create a source file to copy and folder that contain that source file, under src/test/resources (if you use maven folder structure). The test method verify if a new file,the result of copy,exist. 
The test code is something like following:

```
@Test
 public void testCatenaCorretta_crea_civetta() {
    // given
    File fe = new File(pathFolder+"/copiedXmlFile.xml");
    //when
    sut.copyXMLFile();

    //then
    assertThat(fe.exists(), equalTo(true));
};`enter code here`
```

NOTE: sut stand for system unde test